# Applying for jobs in Firefox 52.0 does not work

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs, firefox

Firstly, the upload file part of the form did not work but I thought I would get around that by adding a link in my message. However, when I went to submit the application it did not complete and hung on the screen.

Unfortunately, I didn't think to look in the inspector at the time to check for any output (and I don't want to repeat the submission!). The same process worked fine in Safari 10.0.3. I am on macOS 10.12.3

Let me know if I can provide any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this issue, and I'm sorry that you experienced it.

What happened was an XSRF failure: there was likely a race condition between the token's changing server-side and your sending your application.  This condition is more likely if the browser has been open to the same page for some time.

You did, at some point, manage to send an application to the employer (once), so there is no need to repeat your submission.

Comment: Ah, I understand the XSRF reasonings but perhaps there is a way for you to refresh the token periodically via AJAX or, on submission, provide a clear message as to why the application was rejected.